# Android ImageView and ImageButton Scaling

Tags: android, imageview, imagebutton

For Android Image View .. how to scale 1081*373 Image Button to match the width of Image View and be fixed height ??

i tried match parent for width if image button but it' details not appear ... look like Zoomed image ?? and can't use Gravity ??

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/mainempty"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/about"



    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

```
public class MyBanner extends ImageView {
public MyBanner(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyBanner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyBanner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = width * 373 / 1081;
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

}

in xml

```
<your.package.MyBanner
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/about"/>
```